# PMVS definition of "n-adjacent"

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-vision

I am currently reading over Yasutaka Furukawa et al.'s Paper "Accurate, Dense, and Robust Multi-View Stereopsis" ([PDF available here](http://willow.ai.uiuc.edu/ponce_grp/publication/paper/cvpr07a.pdf)), where they describe an MVS-algorithm for reconstructing a 3D point-cloud from images.

I do understand the concepts and the main steps, but there is one detail that I am struggling with. This may be because I am not an English native speaker, so maybe a small hint would be enough.

On page 4 of the linked source, in chapter 3.2 "Expansion", there is the definition of "n-adjacent" patches:

```
|(c(p)−c(p'))·n(p)|+|(c(p)−c(p'))·n(p')| < 2ρ_2
```

My question is about ρ_2, that is described as in the following:

> [...] ρ_2 is determined automatically as the distance at the depth of the 
>   midpoint of c(p) and c(p') corresponding to an image displacement of β1 pixels 
>   in R(p).

I do not understand what "distance" in this context should be, and I do not understand the stated correspondence to the image  displacement.

I know that this is a very specific question, but since this paper is somewhat popular I hoped, that there is somebody, that can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I do get it now.

It just means, that ρ_2 is the distance you have to move in a plane, located as far away from the camera (depth) as the midpoint of c(p) and c(p'), so that you get a displacement of β1 pixels in the image showing the scene.